# Missing meta and alt key?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, texmacs

Long time ago I used texmacs alot. Now I try to use texmacs again for some math stuff
but I never get the <kbd>Meta</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> key working on Windows or on Ubunut in virtualbox.

Any idea how I can solve this issue? I found nothing useful with google. It seems that pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> key as <kbd>Meta</kbd> key and Alt as Alt key does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

pressing twice ESC_key is equivalent to Alt_key.
**ESC ESC = Alt**
e.g.
If you want enter equation with
Alt+$
on windows-7 you should try 
ESC ESC $
means **[ESC_key] [ESC_key] [$]**

is that what you want to ask?????